# What does a density of states (DOS) plot show?

Tags: density-functional-theory, solid-state-physics, density-of-states, terminology

I have plotted the density of states using GGA-PBE exchange correlation functional for magnesium silcide but I really do not know what the equations involved are in this process, and how they relate to DFT?

[image: Density of States Plot]

Comment: +1 But only one question per post please. For example if you ask what DOS means, then asking what a different thing means ought to be asked in a separate post. Also, can you cut out some of the whitespace in this picture so that it looks better?

Comment: @TristanMaxson thanks so much for doing that!!

Comment: You may take a look at this post: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1791/properties-that-can-be-deduced-from-band-structure-and-dos/2396#2396

Answer (score 4):

From the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_of_states) page, the density of states (DOS):

> In solid state physics and condensed matter physics, the density of states (DOS) of a system describes the proportion of states that are to be occupied by the system at each energy. The density of states is defined as $D(E) = N(E)/V$, where $N(E)\delta E$ is the number of states in the system of volume $V$ whose energies lie in the range from $E$ and $E + \delta E$.

The DOS is not directly linked to DFT, it is a solid state concept about how the electrons are energetically distributed. The DFT is the method used to calculate it (there are other method that can be used).